# GAE JPA Illegal argument when trying to edit entites from query

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

i am breaking my self with this problem and i would need some help. I am trying to edit queries but i keep getting this error

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument
 ...
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: operating on too many entity groups in a single transaction.
 ...
```

this is the part of code i use to update records

```
final EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

try {
    //em.getTransaction().begin();

    {
        Query q = em.createQuery(String.format("SELECT FROM %s cat", NewsContent.class.getSimpleName()));

        int count = 0;
        for(NewsContent nc : (List<NewsContent>) q.getResultList()){
            nc.setOrderTimestamp(nc.getTimestamp());

            count++;
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("NewsContent:\n\t Updated " + count + " records\n" );

    }               

    //em.getTransaction().commit()
} finally {
    //if(em.getTransaction().isActive())
    //  em.getTransaction().rollback();
    em.close();
}
```

this is the part from persistance.xml

```
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>

        <property name="datanucleus.singletonEMFForName" value="true"/>

    </properties>
```

and this is JPA Entity(I removed setters and getters)

```
@Entity
public class NewsContent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Key ID;

String api_key;

String author_username;
String author_displayname;

String organization;
String organization_displayname;

long timestamp;

String api_type;

long order_timestamp;

Text text = null;

String title = null;
String title2 = null;

String extra = null;
String extra_desc = null;

Boolean featured = false;

String category = null;

String imageID = null;
String image_serving_url = null;

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does the line containing setOrderTimestamp throw the exception?  This software by itself looks correct, but there is only one Entity being accessed.  That suggests that other code in the application might have an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: Actually it em.close(); causes this.

Answer (score 0):

Your JPQL is incorrect.

```
SELECT FROM %s cat
```

It should be

```
Select cat from %s cat
```

A common format of jpql that picks all the columns from a table.

```
select o from TableName o where o.id=1
```

If you wish to pick a single column, then it will be

```
select o.colName from TableName o where o.id=1
```